# how to redirect reset password page to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

If the registered user reset his password the page is redirecting to login page. Instead of that I want to redirect to homepage. How to achieve this task?

Comment: what is the url for reset password?

Answer (score 1):

You might even think about to just implement an observer which listens on `http_response_send_before` and checks for current frontend/controller/action then change the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This redirect is written in the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` inside the `resetPasswordPostAction()` function.

In this function the code `$this->_redirect('*/*/login');` after 
`$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));` is responsible for the redirection.

You need to change `$this->_redirect('*/*/login');` to `$this->_redirect('')`

Note: It is a better idea to create a plugin and override the `Mage_Customer_AccountController`, amending the `resetPasswordPostAction()` as you need.

[How to override a Magento controller](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+To+Overload+a+Controller)